# Write an infinitely nested generator comprehension

Tags: code-golf, python

The goal is to create a generator generator [...] generator generator comprehension.

1. The generator must be created via [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work).
2. The following expression must be valid for any number of nestings: `next(next(next(next(next(generator)))))`.

The winner is whoever achieves this with the fewest number of bytes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>31</s> <s>26</s></sup> 25 bytes

```
x=(x for()in iter(set,1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY7K2w1KhTS8os0NDPzFDJLUos0ilNLdAw1NSHyN80rFWwVKriAKhQyFYBKihLz0lM1DA0MNK24FICgoCgzr0SjUhPMAanNS60A8SHaYdYAAA)

If assignment is not allowed:

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>77</s> <s>72</s></sup> 71 bytes

```
(gc.get_referrers(sys._getframe())[0]for()in iter(set,1))
import gc,sys
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYzBCsIwEETv_Yo97kIt7U2Env0IlVLKJubQpGxWSL_FS0D0n_wbo3Uuwwzz5v5aVr0Gnx-pPz9vanb79xHt1FjWQdiwCEvEuMZmKJWRcWYkOrUXEwTJeXDKgpG17ogqNy9BFOxUF-J_15UlOChTGb1l7NqWDhUULeK8YqJfSNCD5_TNG5jz5h8)

(this is bad code)

-5 bytes on both solutions thanks to @ovs

Comment: Wow, very cool! Thanks for demoing this, I have been trying to figure it out for a while now.

Comment: You can save a couple bytes by using a builtin function instead of the lambda, e.g. `iter(int,1)`

Answer (score 7):

@pxeger's solution is pretty much the end of this challenge. A generator expression *must* include code like `(a for b in c)`, where `a` must be a generator which behaves like the outer generator expression behaves. Either `a` refers to the outer generator itself, or `a` is a shorter solution to this problem; so a shortest solution must look like `x=(x for b in c)`. For this to *be* a solution, then `c` must be an infinite iterator.

I don't have a proof that `iter(int,1)` is the shortest possible way to make an infinite iterator, but it seems unbeatable. Otherwise, the only way to improve on @pxeger's solution is if you can write an infinite iterator in fewer than 11 bytes.

---

If we relax the rule requiring the result to be created using a generator expression, then here's a few other ideas:

Using `iter`: ([18 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhabKmwzS1KLNHISc5NSEq0qdAw1IRI3zSsVbBUquNLyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQwNDDStuBSAoKAoM69Eo1ITzAGpzUutAPEh2mHmAwA))

```python
x=iter(lambda:x,1)
```

Using `yield`: ([23 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhbbU1LTFNI0NK0qM1NzUkAsrgpbIAmRvWleqWCrUMGVll-kkKmQmadQlJiXnqphaGCgacWlAAQFRZl5JRqVmmAOSG1eagWID9EOswQA))

```python
def f():yield f()
x=f()
```

Using `itertools.cycle`: ([44 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3dTJzC_KLShQyS1KLSvLzc4oVEosVMrkqbDP1kiuTc1I1cqxso2M1uXK0bSt0oHrMKxVsFSq40vKLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM1DA0MNK24FICgoCgzr0SjUhPMAanNS60A8SHaYVYDAA))

```python
import itertools as i
x=i.cycle(l:=[])
l+=x,
```

---

That said, if the rule is only that the *outer-most* generator be created using a generator expression, and the results after that need not be generators (just things that `next` works on, i.e. any iterators), then `a` in the code above can be some solution to the relaxed challenge, instead of a self-reference: ([32 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweIK25ilpSVpuhY3FTSqrGwzS1KLNHISc5NSEq2qdAw10_KLFOIVMvOiDWM1oerMKxVsFSq4QDKZQBmFosS89FQNQwMDTSsuBSAoKMrMK9Go1ARzQGrzUitAfIj2BQsgNAA))

```python
(z:=iter(lambda:z,1)for _ in[1])
```

This method still can't beat @pxeger's solution, unless there is a solution to the relaxed version of the challenge more than 6 bytes shorter than `z:=iter(lambda:z,1)`. This seems pretty unlikely, and even if it is possible, it would presumably be an infinite iterator; so it would still be shorter if you plugged it into @pxeger's solution instead of this one.

Comment: I thought `iter` created an iterator, not a generator, are they the same thing? Also, I think the challenge requires using a generator comprehension.

Comment: @user *"If we relax the rule requiring the result to be created using a generator expression"*

Comment: I missed that, sorry. I think you do also need a main answer that does comply with the challenge, though.

Comment: @user I don't believe it is possible to write a good solution which is substantially different to pxeger's solution, as I explained in the first half of my answer. Either the `a` part of the generator expression refers to the generator expression itself, in which case you get a version of their solution, or it does not, in which case the `a` part is a shorter solution to the problem.

Comment: There's a way to create an infinite generator by simultaneously iterating over and appending to a list. Is that worth adding to your answer?

Comment: @pxeger Interesting idea, best I can do is `l=[];l+=l,;x=(x for l[1:]in l)` for 30 bytes. The alternative is `l=[1];x=(l.append(1)or x for _ in l)` for 36 bytes. The slice assignment is shorter than writing `append` but it only works if `l` contains copies of itself, which requires more setup.